# EasyAdmin Bundle - Symfony

Tags: symfony

I work with `EasyAdmin` and I don't know how to add an image in list view.

I would like to add next to the prices two pictures (simply 2 logos) with a link to the website in question. The admin can click on logo `A` or `B` who redirect to the website.

I can insert my links with entiy's priority (Interface with links).

[image: Interface with links].

Here is my code:

## app/config/config.yml

```
list:
fields:
    - { property: 'low_amz', label: 'Amazon' }
    - { property: 'url_amz', label: 'Amz', type: 'url' }

    - { property: 'low_pm', label: 'PriceMinister' }
    - { property: 'url_pm', label: 'Pm', type: 'url' }
```

But how I replace these link's value with my images. The images are stocked in local.

With my thumbnails, it works:

```
 - { property: 'urlPdtImg', type: 'image', label: ' ' }
```

But in my case, I want just to change the value "string" in img. Of course, this does not work:

```
- { property: 'url_pm', label: 'Pm', type: 'url', base_path: '/img/Amazon.svg' }}


EasyAdmin Bundle 1.17.12
Symfony 3.4
```

Have a nice day.

Comment: Did you read https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/list-search-show-configuration.html#image-data-type ?

Comment: @DirkJ.Faber 
Yes I did, I work with it for my thumbnails: 
- { property: 'urlPdtImg', type: 'image', label: ' ', sortable: false }

Answer (score 0):

Here are my files:

File config.yml:

```
- { property: 'url_amz', label: ' ', type: 'url', template: 'easy_admin/fields/_url1.html.twig' }
```

File _url.html.twig

```
<a href="{{ value }}">
<img src="{{ asset('Img/PM.svg') }}" alt="Amazon logo" style="height: 30px;"/>
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahW51.jpg)